# Joins - get row from one table then get all rows that match in another table?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. Gallery and Joins.

```
Gallery
id | title
 1 | Dog Gallery
 2 | Cat Gallery

Joins
id | gallery_id | picture_id
 1 |      1     |     100
 2 |      1     |     101
 3 |      2     |     56
 4 |      1     |     102
```

I want to get id, gallery title from gallery - where id is equal to a specific id but also get all of the rows from joins where gallery id equals a specific gallery id.

So for above if the id was 1. I would want the dog gallery from gallery and picture_ids 100,101 and 102 from joins.

I've tried a left join but it only gets on (the first) picture id out of joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an `INNER JOIN` query

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, b.id as joins_id, b.picture_id
FROM Gallery a
INNER JOIN Joins b
ON a.id = b.gallery_id
WHERE a.id = ?
```

#### [Live SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0bfb/3)